# Making one or separate database for two system?

Tags: database, integration, vbulletin

We have a Vbulletin 4 forum as well as a gaming CMS (not Vbulletin CMS). We want to connect the database of these systems, integration with CMS.

My question is that: Is it better to make separate database for each one and then integrate two system together or put both in one database? Which one is better and lighter?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to use only one DB.
Each CMS (I assume vb forum IS a CMS) should have its dedicated database (but the DBs can be hosted on the same serv).
Each CMS uses plugins and has a very special way to work with the database, so basicaly they would not be able to share information directly via database.
Many CMS on the same DB = risk of conflict.

(depending what do you need to integrate) You need to use a bridge, that's safer.